# MAX() doesn't return NULL rows from LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, null, left-join

This will return multiple rows:

```
SELECT w.word_id, w.word_word, w.word_visits, w.word_created_unix, b.bid_per_visit
FROM keywords_words AS w
LEFT JOIN keywords_bids AS b
ON w.word_id = b.bid_word_id WHERE w.word_word LIKE 'an%'
ORDER BY w.word_visits DESC
LIMIT 10
```

But this will only return rows where there is a bid in keywords_bids:

```
SELECT w.word_id, w.word_word, w.word_visits, w.word_created_unix, MAX(b.bid_per_visit)
FROM keywords_words AS w
LEFT JOIN keywords_bids AS b
ON w.word_id = b.bid_word_id WHERE w.word_word LIKE 'an%'
ORDER BY w.word_visits DESC
LIMIT 10
```

How do I get it to return the `MAX(b.bid_per_visit)` if there is a bid, and zero if there isn't any bids.

Not excluding rows from the original LIKE search basically.

Comment: Your second query will return a single row

Comment: what's the bid entity here?

Comment: @Mihai that's what I'm trying to avoid. I'm trying to get a list of maximum bids for various keywords from my keywords_words table.

Comment: @KP. a bid is a row in the keywords_bids table that joins on the word_id

Comment: You need a GROUP BY in your second query together with  `IFNULL(MAX(b.bid_per_visit), 0)`

Comment: @AmyNeville,  you need show input and expected output to get better understanding

Comment: @Mihai GROUP BY word_word seems to have done the trick thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use coalesce:

```
...
MAX(coalesce(b.bid_per_visit, 0))
...
```

Or don't group by and simply:

```
...
coalesce(b.bid_per_visit, 0)
...
```

`coalesce()` returns the first non-null value in its list of values. With left joins, nulls are returned for the joiner table is there's no matching row.

Answer (score 0):

use of  IFNULL(MAX(b.bid_per_visit),0) solve your problem which will return 0 if MAX(b.bid_per_visit) is null and return  maximum of b.bid_per_visit if its not null.